# SQL Server how to extract only the numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have those kind of values in my table and I want to retrieve only the numeric value.

How can I do that?

Thanks

```
\physicaldisk(1 d:)\disk read bytes/sec              49920420.7711372
\physicaldisk(2 e:)\disk read bytes/sec                             0
\physicaldisk(0 c:)\disk bytes/sec                   1666197.41297793
\physicaldisk(2 e:)\disk bytes/sec                   4093.85113753791
\physicaldisk(3 t:)\disk bytes/sec                   4605.58252973014
\physicaldisk(2 e:)\disk write bytes/sec             4093.85113753791
\physicaldisk(3 t:)\disk write bytes/sec             4605.58252973014
\physicaldisk(1 d:)\disk write bytes/sec             67073657.0374211
\physicaldisk(3 t:)\disk read bytes/sec                             0
\physicaldisk(0 c:)\disk read bytes/sec              1567944.98567702
\physicaldisk(1 d:)\disk bytes/sec                   116994077.808558
\physicaldisk(2 e:)\disk reads/sec                                  0
\physicaldisk(3 t:)\disk reads/sec                                  0
\physicaldisk(1 d:)\disk reads/sec                    57.969571771777
\physicaldisk(3 t:)\disk transfers/sec               8.99527837837919
\physicaldisk(0 c:)\disk transfers/sec               71.9622270270335
\physicaldisk(3 t:)\disk writes/sec                  8.99527837837919
\physicaldisk(0 c:)\disk writes/sec                   2.9984261261264
```

Comment: you might need to search the internet for `sql regex` and using this you can detect the decimal valus and not the text

Comment: Can you just locate the first space from the right and then take substring from that position to the end?

Comment: Is the physical drive number always a single digit in the same position? Otherwise you could locate the first open parenthesis and space and extract the substring between them. Did you have some other numeric value in mind?

Comment: Looks like you can just grab rightmost 25 characters or so and cast to `numeric`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works in SQL Server:

```
select REVERSE(left(REVERSE(MyCol), charindex(' ', REVERSE(MyCol)) - 1))
from Table1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/199dba/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([MyCol] varchar(max))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([MyCol])
VALUES
    ('\physicaldisk(1 d:)\disk read bytes/sec              49920420.7711372'),
('\physicaldisk(2 e:)\disk read bytes/sec                             0'),
('\physicaldisk(0 c:)\disk bytes/sec                   1666197.41297793'),
('\physicaldisk(2 e:)\disk bytes/sec                   4093.85113753791'),
('\physicaldisk(3 t:)\disk bytes/sec                   4605.58252973014'),
('\physicaldisk(2 e:)\disk write bytes/sec             4093.85113753791'),
('\physicaldisk(3 t:)\disk write bytes/sec             4605.58252973014'),
('\physicaldisk(1 d:)\disk write bytes/sec             67073657.0374211'),
('\physicaldisk(3 t:)\disk read bytes/sec                             0'),
('\physicaldisk(0 c:)\disk read bytes/sec              1567944.98567702'),
('\physicaldisk(1 d:)\disk bytes/sec                   116994077.808558'),
('\physicaldisk(2 e:)\disk reads/sec                                  0'),
('\physicaldisk(3 t:)\disk reads/sec                                  0'),
('\physicaldisk(1 d:)\disk reads/sec                    57.969571771777'),
('\physicaldisk(3 t:)\disk transfers/sec               8.99527837837919'),
('\physicaldisk(0 c:)\disk transfers/sec               71.9622270270335'),
('\physicaldisk(3 t:)\disk writes/sec                  8.99527837837919'),
('\physicaldisk(0 c:)\disk writes/sec                   2.9984261261264')

;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select REVERSE(left(REVERSE(MyCol), charindex(' ',REVERSE(MyCol))-1))
from Table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/199dba/2/0)**:

```
|                  |
|------------------|
| 49920420.7711372 |
|                0 |
| 1666197.41297793 |
| 4093.85113753791 |
| 4605.58252973014 |
| 4093.85113753791 |
| 4605.58252973014 |
| 67073657.0374211 |
|                0 |
| 1567944.98567702 |
| 116994077.808558 |
|                0 |
|                0 |
|  57.969571771777 |
| 8.99527837837919 |
| 71.9622270270335 |
| 8.99527837837919 |
|  2.9984261261264 |
```